# Spring webflow redirect not working for Portlets

Tags: spring-webflow-2, spring-portlet-mvc

I have to implement inter-portlet communication functionality. The functionality is as below:

1) user clicks on "save as" link on "createStep1.jsp".

2) the below mentioned webflow `saveDraftStep1` is called, the draft is saved in the database.

3) user is navigated to another portlet `myportlet` and the successfully saved message is displayed there.

Somehow the webflow is not redirecting to the url I specify in the `externalRedirect`. It stays on the same page. Below is the code:

```xml
<view-state id="createStep1">
   <transition on="saveDraftStep1" to="redirectView" >
         <evaluate expression="myAction.bindAndValidate" /> 
         <evaluate expression="myService.saveDraft(saveCriteria, externalContext.nativeRequest,externalContext.nativeResponse )" />
    </transition>
</view-state>
<end-state id="redirectView" view="externalRedirect:http://www.google.com" />
```

Ideally i want to replace the google url with my portlet url e.g: `localhost:8080/myportlet`.

Answer (score 0):

If either of those `evaluate` calls returns an error, the transition won't be taken. Perhaps that is what's happening?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but there are no errors. i even tried the following without any "evaluate"    <transition on="saveDraftStep1" to="redirectView" >
   </transition>
  <end-state id="redirectView" view="externalRedirect:http://www.google.com" />

Comment: So the transition works if it's not to a redirect? Or if it's not an externalRedirect?

Comment: yes. the transition works fine without redirect. I fixed the issue now. I had to overwrite the "handleExecutionOutcome" method as below. public boolean handleExecutionOutcome(FlowExecutionOutcome outcome    try {
    
    response.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);
    return true; // outcome manually handled
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

   ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) {

  {